# Capture shellexecute() response in delphi

Tags: delphi, shellexecute, perfmon

I am executing Logman.exe by using `ShellExecuteExW` in Delphi. How can we capture the result of this function

```
  Params    :=    'START '+<<DATA COLLECTOR SET NAME>>+
                  ' -s '+ MachineIP;
                  ' -u '+ UserName.QuotedString('"')+' 
                        '+Password.QuotedString('"');

  ZeroMemory(@ShellExecuteInfo, SizeOf(ShellExecuteInfo));
  ShellExecuteInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  ShellExecuteInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

  ShellExecuteInfo.Wnd := 0;
  ShellExecuteInfo.lpVerb := nil;
  ShellExecuteInfo.lpFile := Pchar('LOGMAN.EXE');
  ShellExecuteInfo.lpParameters := PChar(StartParam);
  ShellExecuteInfo.lpDirectory := nil;
  ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;

  ShellExecuteExW(@ShellExecuteInfo);
```

if we execute START command from command prompt then it results the 
  following string

> 'The command completed successfully'

I need to capture this string in the above code.

If we use the '>' operator in command then we can write the output to the 
  text file.To read this string, I have to load the file in my code 
  which is not acceptable in my project.

Please share any thoughts to get the string resulted in above 
  `ShellExecuteExW()` procedure by using any Delphi procedures.

Comment: You don't capture the output when calling `ShellExecute`. You instead create the process using `CreateProcess`, and attach pipes to stdout and stderr and capture the output that way. But isn't there an API for this anyway, so that you can do it cleanly?

Comment: Thanks david. I cound not find any API for this. Could you please share any API if you knows

Comment: I already did. It's called `CreateProcess`.

Comment: There is no *single* WIN32 API to automatically spawn a process and capture its output for you, you have to do it manually using `CreatePipe()`, `CreateProcess()`, and `ReadFile()` (see [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)), or find a 3rd party wrapper (there are many available).

Comment: Thanks David and Remy. I am able to capture the output successfully with Create process().